# Curve fitting testing basics questions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, curve-fitting

I'm learning all this stuff, so bear with me. A marketing professor in a university class, did the following:

He wanted to do a projection from a very small data set of just 7 numbers. Using Excel the logarithmic fitting looked closest and the resulting R^2 was 0.983.

What puzzled me is what he did next:

Using some Excel functions, he did an analysis of variance comparing the original set of data to a linear regression fitting of the same data. He set the test up as an hypothesis testing and the resulting "p" was a bit smaller than 0.005. So he concluded that that proved that the earlier, logarithmic fitting, was all good and right because the straight line from the linear regression (R^2=0.785) was yielding a very good result. Then he proceeded to do the predictive projection using the logarithmic equation.

When questioned about why he performed the fitting test on a different curve, he said that it was done for simplicity and didn't want to answer any other question regarding the process.

My questions are:

Why do I need to perform another test for the fitting if I already have R^2?

What would be the definitive (at least in this case) way to test if a curve fitting is good? The data set is very small and doesn't resemble anything like a normal distribution.

Could not he have performed an equally simple goodness of fit test (would X^2 work in this case?) comparing the original data and calculated values from the logarithmic equation of the first fitting?

While I can easily see that the first logarithmic fitting is better than the linear, the first could actually be anything and way off, and the second test will always yield a good result, so I believe that this, as part of a test, would need a very good explanation right?. What would be the best explanation that fully justifies this testing method? Would comparing both R^2 suffice?

I can add the actual data and results to clarify this question if necessary.

Thanks in advance.